# Is it possible to output full command names with `lsof -nP -i4UDP`?

Tags: files, lsof

Is it possible to output full command name with `lsof -nP -i4UDP`?

I've been looking in the manual for a suitable option, like `-V` (see below), but it doesn't result in full `COMMAND` names, i.e. `systemd-resolve` is displayed as `systemd-r`:

```
$ sudo lsof -V -nP -i4UDP
COMMAND    PID            USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
avahi-dae  437           avahi   12u  IPv4  12982      0t0  UDP *:5353 
avahi-dae  437           avahi   14u  IPv4  12984      0t0  UDP *:45006 
cups-brow  449            root    7u  IPv4  12149      0t0  UDP *:631 
systemd-r  485 systemd-resolve   12u  IPv4  14694      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.53:53 
systemd-r  485 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  14695      0t0  UDP *:5355 
dhclient   629            root    6u  IPv4  14985      0t0  UDP *:68 
minissdpd 1186            root    4u  IPv4  19639      0t0  UDP *:1900
```

Answer (score 10):

From `man lsof`:

> ```
> +c w     defines the maximum number of initial characters of the name,
>          supplied by the UNIX dialect, of the UNIX command associated with a
>          process to be printed in the COMMAND  column.  (The lsof default is nine.)
>
>          Note  that  many UNIX dialects do not supply all command name characters
>          to lsof in the files and structures from which lsof obtains command name.
>          Often  dialects limit the number  of characters supplied in those sources.
>          For example, Linux 2.4.27 and Solaris 9 both limit command name length to
>          16 characters.
>
>          If w is zero ('0'), all command characters supplied to lsof by the UNIX
>          dialect will be printed.
>
>          If  w  is  less  than the length of the column title, ``COMMAND'', it will
>          be raised to that length.
> ```

Given that, you can add `+c0` to get all that are available:

```
$ sudo lsof -V -nP -i4UDP +c0
COMMAND         PID            USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd-resolve 176 systemd-resolve   11u  IPv4  11204      0t0  UDP *:5355
```

Comment: Thanks Andy! Do you know what's the purpose of `-V`? Also, *UNIX dialect* should be understood as the underlying OS, e.g. Linux or macOS, from which `lsof` obtains the `COMMAND` column information?

Comment: @Shuzheng See `man lsof` for info on `-V`: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html .  Yes, _UNIX dialect_ means the underlying OS.

Comment: Note that, in any case, what's reported here is the *process name* (same as in `ps -o comm` or `ps` alone) which on Linux is limited to 15 bytes in length (which explains why `systemd-resolved` is truncated to `systemd-resolve` here).